# Integer domain enveloping algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

I must prove that if $L$ is a Lie algebra and denoting $U(L)$ the enveloping algebra, then $U(L)$ hasn't zero divisions (e.g. if $ab=0 \,\,\, a,b \in U(L)$ then $a=0$ or $b=0$). Some ideas?

Comment: hint: use the PBW basis.

Comment: @mt_ What is it?

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Birkhoff%E2%80%93Witt_theorem -- the PBW basis is the basis $x^ay^b\cdots $ where $x,y,\ldots$ is a basis of the Lie algebra.  The PBW basis shows that the enveloping algebra has a filtration whose associated graded algebra is a polynomial algebra, so is a domain.

Comment: @mt_ Could you give me a sckhet of proof?

Comment: Here is a rough sketch.  1) the UEA has a filtration such that the associated graded algebra is isomorphic to the polynomial algebra on the Lie algebra (this is the content of the PBW theorem) 2) if a ring $R$ has a filtration whose associated graded is a domain, then $R$ is a domain.  This is in Jacobson's book *Lie Algebras* for example